# How to exclude specific resource folder from apk

Tags: java, android, gradle

I need to remove several resource folders from apk.

Now I have the following folders:

```
res/drawable
res/drawable-land
res/drawable-land-xxhdpi
```

In the process of gradle assembly, I need not to include folders **drawable-land** and **drawable-land-xxhdpi** in apk, is it possible to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can delete the folders?

Comment: No. I want to be able to customize the build option if necessary. This can be a forced build option for mobile and a tablet option.

Comment: Looks like you'll have to maintain separate code base for that. Have a look at this - https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#CreatingApks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#product-flavors)

In the module's `build.gradle` :

```
buildTypes {
    ...
}

# this is mandatory since Android Studio 3
flavorDimensions "a_flavor_dimension"

productFlavors {
    minimal_resources {
        # optionnal if there is only one dimension
        dimension "a_flavor_dimension"
    }
    additional_resources {
        dimension "a_flavor_dimension"
    }
}
```

Each time you create a resource, or a resource directory (right click on *res* / *New* / *Android resource directory*), choose the `additional_resources` flavor in the *Source set* selector.

The files are located in `src/additional_resources/res/...` instead of of `src/main/res/...`

When generating the apk you will be able to choose which flavor(s) you want to build.