# How can I exclude a folder upon compiling APK(Release)

Tags: android, kotlin

just want to ask if how can I exclude a folder upon compiling a Release APK. I have this Resources folder filled with json files used for my simulations(Debug only) but would want to exclude this when compiling to a Release Apk.

Kindly see attached image [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6gWe.png).

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: I am using json files to simulate data, its like my test data, applicable only when in debug mode/variant.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48684149/how-to-exclude-specific-resource-folder-from-apk)?

Comment: thank you for the reference, will check on it.

Comment: Okay no issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **different** assets folder, like:

```
app/src/main/assets
app/src/debug/assets
app/src/release/assets
```

Or you can define different src folders in the build.gradle file:

```
sourceSets {

        main.java.srcDirs = ['...']
        main.res.srcDirs = ['...']
        main.assets.srcDirs = ['...']
        debug.assets.srcDirs = ['...']
        flavor1.assets.srcDirs = ['...']
    }
```

To check the "debug" value you can use the default BuildConfig.DEBUG.
In the same way you can define your own boolean value:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "MYVALUE", "true"
        }
        release {
            buildConfigField "boolean", "MYVALUE", "false"
        }
    }
```

The automatically-generated BuildConfig class will contain the following fields based on the directive above:

```
public class BuildConfig {
    // ... other generated fields ...
    public static final boolean MYVALUE = false;
}
```

Comment: No problem, if it works though, consider accepting answer :)

Comment: Hello i end up using the different assets folder. Than you very much for this!!

Comment: hello again mina, I am very happy to hear that, do you think you can accept the answer by clicking on the Nike button? :D

Comment: there you go :)))